# Salt Orchestration

Tags: salt-stack, orchestration

My question is "simple".
I would like to execute specific salt.state in my orchestration only if the previous fail for some reason. Basically I'm looking for opposite of - require:

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `onfail`
You can check the doc here: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html#requisites-onfail

For question like this, you can go straight to [Slack](http://saltstackcommunity.slack.com)